# How can I display text labels for the features of a geojson layer in Openlayers 3 while using WebGl renderer?

Tags: openlayers-3, geojson

I'm able to create a style in Openlayers 3 for a vector source.

The style is meant to display one of the attributes in text format for all the features in the vector source.

The map perfectly displays the points along with the text except for when I switch to WebGl renderer..

I receive the following error:

'Uncaught TypeError: a.Tb is not a function'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebGL support for text rendering was added in 4.3.0 and 4.3.1